# Does RandomAccessIterator imply that the data is continuous in memory?

Tags: c++, iterator, random-access

The other iterator types surely don't have the implication that they point to continuous data, but I'm wondering if I can treat RandomAccessIterators as if they point to a buffer of continuous data – i.e. they could be converted to pointers to data.

Is this assumption correct? Can I always safely use `&*it` and get a pointer not just to one element, but to a continuous buffer, if `it` is a RandomAccessIterator?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not a valid assumption. The standard library itself has a counterexample in `std::deque`:

[from cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque):

> As opposed to `std::vector`, the elements of a deque are not stored contiguously: typical implementations use a sequence of individually allocated fixed-size arrays.

`std::deque`'s `iterator` is a RandomAccessIterator:

[[deque.overview]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/deque#deque.overview-1)

> A deque is a sequence container that, like a vector ([[vector]](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector)), supports random access iterators.

If you want a guarantee of contiguous memory, you don't need to wait long: the guarantee will be provided by the ContiguousIterator in C++17.<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>the ContiguousIterator concept was proposed in a sequence of documents ending in [N4284](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4284.html), and adopted in [November 2014](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/#mailing2014-07)</sup>

Comment: It worth mentionong that C++17 will add `ContiguousIterator` category.

Comment: [This is what I found](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/11/new-standard-library-papers-adopted-for-cpp17). Sadly, it only a concept which gives guarantees to certain containers, it didn't add corresponding tag, as it apparently broke code.

Comment: unfortunately, `ContiguousIterator` in C++17 has no practical use https://stackoverflow.com/a/52277825/8414561